# how undefined properties are working using this keyword?

Tags: php

Below classes are working fine, trying to learn MVC and I just want to know why. It is probably very simple but I could not understand.

1. So In controller class I have initiated View object(Defined somewhere else) and assigned to $this->view. Now Why is this not giving me any error as I have not defined the view property anywhere in the controller class neither it is extending.
2. Same thing with the error class. How come $this->view->msg is working fine as msg property is not defined anywhere neither in parent nor in Error controller itself.

How these are working on the fly.

```
        <?php

    class Controller {

        function __construct() {
            echo 'main controller <br/>';
            $this->view = new View();
        }

    }

?>
```

Error class extending the controller

```
    <?php

class Error extends Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'This is error mate';
        $this->view->msg = 'This page does not exit by msg';
        $this->view->render('error/index');
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: objects in PHP are pretty much dictionaries, so you're just able to assign new attributes on-the-fly. But you're right that better practice would be to define them explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically add properties to objects at any time, they do not need to be declared in advance; just like regular variables if you will. That's all.

The downside is that these properties will be `public`, which you may not desire, and that it's bad practice because it makes the structure of the class less obvious.